# how to make batch file for simple msbuild commands

Tags: msbuild

I have below a ms build command which want to execute as a batch file so that i can automate it further.
So can any one tell me how to make a batch file (*.bat) which will execute the command bellow with one click of a button ?

Commands:

```
set msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
call %msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe "D:\tmc600\WIX_Related_files\RIO600_ConnPack_Ver.1.5_WIX\tmc_SetupProject.wixproj" /p:Platform="x86" /p:configuration="Release"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running your set command as written and replace "call" with "start" in the call command.

```
  @echo off
  Your set command
  start "" "%msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe" "D:\tmc600\WIX_Related_files\RIO600_ConnPack_Ver.1.5_WIX\tmc_SetupProject.wixproj" /p:Platform="x86" /p:configuration="Release"
  pause
```

Save as name.bat. You may need to work on the parameters in the Start. There's a good explanation here: http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Comment: thanks. But i am getting error as "msbuild.exe" command not found

Comment: Put quotes " around start as shown in my edited answer. Should get you past command not found. For me, without D drive, I get:
"The system cannot find the file D:\tmc600\WIX_Related_files\RIO600_ConnPack_Ver.1.5_WIX\tmc_SetupProject.wixproj."